# Xcode Image Displayed in the SKScene editor is black when run

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an Image in my SKScene editor. The SKScene looks like this.

[image: image link]

But when I run the program it looks like this.

[image: image link]

The image looks fine in the SKScene but then it looks black when the program is run. I have never seen this problem before. What do I do to fix this.

**EDIT:** This is the code I use to present the SKScene:

```
let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene2")
        scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFit

        let Action2 = SKAction.run {

            self.view?.presentScene(scene)
        }

       shape.run(SKAction.sequence([Action1, Action2]))
```

Comment: Without showing the actual code you use to display the `SKScene` your question is considered off-topic here on SO. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50309726/edit) your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: Sorry but I am confused. How does the code presenting the SKScene affect the image. Other images work when the scene is being presented with the code so why is only one not working.

Comment: @DávidPásztor please respond to my comments and edits so I can remove the ban

Comment: I'm not the one who voted to close your question, but I've given you a reopen vote after the edits, whether your question will be reopened or not is up to the community now.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Ok... Do you have a solution to my problem